# Qualys: Weak SSL/TLS Key Exchange

Tags: linux, ssl, redhat

In a Qualys vulnerability report on a RHEL 8.6 server where a CA endevor bridge for git is installed, it detects the following vulnerability:

```
QID 38863 - Weak SSL/TLS Key Exchange
```

Offering as a result of the analysis the following:

```
PROTOCOL    CIPHER  NAME    GROUP   KEY-SIZE    FORWARD-SECRET  CLASSICAL-STRENGTH  QUANTUM-STRENGTH
TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   DHE     1024    yes 80  low
TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   DHE     1024    yes 80  low
TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256       DHE     1024    yes 80  low
TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       DHE     1024    yes 80  low
TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          DHE     1024    yes 80  low
TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          DHE     1024    yes 80  low#
```

As a port it tells me: `443`

And indicating as a solution to this vulnerability:

"*Change the SSL/TLS server configuration to only allow strong key exchanges. Key exchanges used on the server should provide at least 112 bits of security, so the minimum key size to not flag this QID should be:*"

```
2048 bit key size for Diffie Hellman (DH) or RSA key exchanges
224 bit key size for Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman (EDCH) key exchange
```

According to what I've been researching, this happens because on TLSv1.2 connections some of the ciphers can negotiate a DHE key size of 1024 bytes.

What would be the best alternative to solve this vulnerability and what steps should I follow?

**Update**

These are the cipher suites available on the server (openssl ciphers -v):

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-CCM          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: On the server software (which provide SSL/TLS) deny leak ciphers.

Comment: According to what I have been reading, the changes in the SSL/TLS configuration may vary depending on the web server you are using (Apache, NGINX, etc.), in this case I have checked that this server has a bridge for git installed, but I am not familiar with this tool.

Comment: If you do not provide the server we can't help you. And I have my doubts this bridge have something to do with SSL/TLS

Comment: When you run nmap against the port with `--ssl-enum-ciphers`, what does it show?

Comment: https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-mainframe-software/devops/ca-endevor-integrations-for-enterprise-devops/1-0/ca-endevor-bridge-for-git.html https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-mainframe-software/devops/ca-endevor-integrations-for-enterprise-devops/1-0/ca-endevor-bridge-for-git/bridge-for-git-security-considerations.html

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which component it is, but those are known old ciphers, one fix would that be to disable them. Windows for example these ciphers are disabled by default starting on Windows Server 2019.

Comment: The server is a redhat 8 and I don't have nmap, use the openssl ciphers -v command to see the available cipher suites, which I have put in the body of the question

Comment: Don't have nmap? `dnf install nmap` and you have nmap. Or if this is public machine you can install it on literally any other computer that has access to that 443 port and check your target machine.

Comment: I can't install any package, it's this server unfortunately

Comment: According to what I was able to investigate, it can be set on the server to only allow strong key exchanges by modifying the file $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security and replace the value from 1024 to 2048 in the following line jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1 .1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024
Has anyone applied that solution?